# Force an image to be centered alone on a page

Tags: graphics, positioning

I'm always facing problems with positioning images at specific places. I posted a question about one week ago and I got an answer for [How do I place an image at the center of the page alone?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116568/how-do-i-place-an-image-at-the-center-of-the-page-alone)

Today I decided to replace the image with an another one. So I expected to get the same positioning but with the new one. It's sticking to the top of the page. I tried everything but still not working. Please check the link to see my code and the answer to it.

Comment: Can you make the image file available for download? The solution may lie there if it's the only thing you have changed.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84310/dedicated-pages-for-figures-and-automatic-scaling-and-use-of-pdflscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find working with figures can be frustrating at times and occasionally chose not to place them in a `figure` environment.  Instead, I use a `minipage`.  By combining `minipage` with the facilities of the `caption` package, you can essentially get the effects of a `figure` environment in terms of lableling and captioning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{figure}{Example Image A}
    \label{fig:fig01}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

\vspace*{\fill}

\noindent
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{Example Image B}
    \label{fig:fig02}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill}

\vspace{\fill}

\pagebreak

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note that, because I want the image's width to be half that of the page **and** because I already set the width of the `minipage` to this width, within the `minipage` the width should not be scaled any further.

The one issue with this approach is that, if you're mixing `floats` with *floatish* `minipage`s, then the numbering can get out of order when LaTeX decides that the first float needs to be pushed to later in the document.